# Find the dimension of $W $ and $V $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

> Let $A$ be a diagonal matrix whose characteristic polynomial is
>   $$P(x) = (x − 16)^8(x − 15)^8(x − 14)^7(x − 13)^7(x − 12)^6(x − 11)^6· · ·(x − 2)(x−1)$$
>   Let $V$ be the set of all $72\times 72$ matrices commuting with $A$. Let $W$ be the subset of $V$ consisting of all diagonal matrices.
>
> $(a)$ find the  dimension of $W ?$
>
> $(b)$ find  the dimension of $V $

---

**My attempt  :**  For  $a)$:  Dimension of  $$W =  2 \sum_{k=1}^{8} k^2=  2.\frac{8(8+1)(16+1)}{6}=408$$

For $b)$ : Dimension of $V = 72$

Is it correct ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: It looks fine. I just don't see why you started your sume with $k=0$ instead of $k=1$.

Comment: thanks u sir @JoséCarlosSantos...i  will edits its

Comment: Both dimensions correct.

Comment: you didnt prove it...

Comment: Why $\dim W > \dim V$, yet $W$ is a subset of $V$?

Comment: Yes I agree with @xbh why is that anyone please???

Comment: It is/was the other way around.